# Ruby on rails Xero integration with Xeroizer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I am doing integration with Xero from ruby on rails with the Xeroizer gem and I cant figure out how to create options for my tracking category from rails.

I have added a tracking category named Branches from the Xero web interface, now I need to add an option to the tracking category each time I add a branch in my app.

```
client = Xeroizer::PrivateApplication.new("the_key", "the_secret",the_path)
option = client.Option.build()
option.tracking_category = client.TrackingCategory.find(the_category_id)
option.name = 'Test'
option.save
```

can any one help me out please?

Comment: Also need help on this...